# Yamaha NP-35's speaker as Windows 11 output

Tags: digital-piano, speakers, windows

I am able to select NP-35 as my output in MacOS but I am unable to select it as a sound output device on windows 11.

I have verified that the keyboard is connected as I am able to use it in Piano Marvel. It is also showing up on Sound, video and game controllers in device manager.

Need some help in figuring out what I need to do so I am able to use the NP-35 speakers as my PC output device.

Comment: Uh, missing a driver maybe?

Comment: I don't see any reason why Yamaha could not make it a class compliant USB device but looks like it indeed has drivers.

Comment: Did you install the [Yamaha USB Driver](https://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical_instruments/keyboards/piaggero/np-35/downloads.html)?